# mongodb - Multiple LET and AS assignments to use within the same pipeline

Tags: mongodb

How to perform multiple `let` and `as` and use them within the same pipeline. I have the following query but assignment defaults to userTo. Both userFrom and userTo are from users collection

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
let: {
  userFrom: "$from",
},
as: "userFrom",
let: {
  userTo: "$to",
},
as: "userTo",
pipeline: [
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$userFrom",
              "$_id"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$userTo",
              "$_id"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using them correctly. `as` specifies the name of the output array of the `$lookup`. There is only 1 result set per lookup so only 1 `as` would be needed.

`let` specifies the variables you want to use in the sub-pipeline. You can put them in an object if you want to use multiple variables.

Your code should look like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        userFrom: "$from",
        userTo: "$to"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$userFrom",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$userTo",
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "userLookup"
    }
  }
])
```